# Variables are overwritten in C

Tags: c, pointers, char

I have this function in C :

`void convertXY(int* x, int* y, char entry[3]);`

Tihs function recieves two pointers to x and y and an array of characters. The entry contain some coordinates like this : 'a7' , 'h13', 'b9', 'd11' and must convert the letter to an integer (x) and same for the number.
For example if entry is 'h13', x will be 8 and y 13.

So here's the full code of my function :

```
void convertXY(int* x, int* y, char entry[3])
{
    int i;
    char alphabet[26] = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

    if(entry[2] == NULL) // if the entry is something like 'a1' we must change it to 'a01'
    {
        entry[2] = entry[1];
        entry[1] = '0';
    }

    for(i = 0; i < 26; i++) // we convert the letter into a number
    {
        if (alphabet[i] == entry[0])
            *y = i;
    }

    *x = charToInt(entry[1]) * 10 + charToInt(entry[2]); // we convert entry[1] and entry[2] from char to int using powers of 10 (10^0 and 10^1).
}
```

And my `charToInt` function :

```
int charToInt(char character)
{
    int i;
    char numbers[10] = "0123456789";

    for(i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        if(numbers[i] == character)
            return i; 
}
```

The problem is that when I use this function, some of my variables are overwritten. I don't know why is that. For example :

```
int variable = 99, x, y;
char entry[3];

printf("variable:%d\n",variable); // prints 99

scanf("%s", &entry);

convertXY(&x, &y, entry);

printf("variable:%d\n",variable); // prints a random number
```

Comment: `scanf("%s", &entry);` => `scanf("%2s", entry);`. What is `entry`? if it's 100, undefined behaviour. don't have enough room in `entry`

Comment: Please stop bean-counting.  Unless you have a RAM-restricted embedded environment, just declare [128] as a minimum for such temporary buffers.

Comment: Side note: there are 27 characters is `"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"` (the last one being `'\0'`, aka *the null character*). For the same reason, there are 11 characters in `"0123456789"`.

Comment: You can alternatively declare `char numbers[10] = {'0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9'}`, which will indeed allocate an array of 10 characters, but you will not be able to perform any string operations on this array (e.g., `strlen`, `strcpy`, `printf` with `"%s"`, etc).

Comment: @goodvibration The code in the question will also allocate an array of 10 elements. There is no trailing terminator appended to the arrays. And how does this prevent calling the string functions on the array? General advice: write **human readable** code.

Comment: @Olaf: 1. The compiler (or maybe even the pre-processor) adds a null character at the end of `"0123456789"` (or any other string literal for that matter). 2. Declaring `char numbers[10] = {'0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9'}` will not "prevent calling the string functions on the array" of course, since there will not be anyone to stop you from doing that, but the result of such action will be undefined behavior.

Comment: @goodvibration: No, it does not, because this will not fit into the array! An array is not a pointer, Read 6.7.9p14 in the standard **carefully**. Appending a trailing `NUL` is a special case and only **if** there is enough space in the target array (or the arrays has no specified size). The compiler will never change the size of an array if that is specifed; this would break a lot of code, expecially legacy code.

Comment: @Olaf: OK, accepted. What about #2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to store 3 charcaters, including `\0` storage must be `char entry[4]`. Otherwise it's undefined behavior.

You don't want to check `NULL`. What you want to know is whether it is of length 2 or not.

```
if(strlen(entry)==2) // if the entry is something like 'a1' we must change it to 'a01'
    {
        entry[2] = entry[1];
        entry[1] = '0';
    }
```

`charToInt` is as simple as this if you are aware of ascii value. I changed the function name to be more suitable as per the context.

```
int digitToInt(char digit)
{
      if( digit <= '9' && digit >= '0') 
      return c-'0';
      return -1;
}
```

Same goes for the letter to integer conversion. If you know it's always between `a` to `z` then you can do this:-

```
void convertXY(int* x, int* y, char entry[3])
{


    if(strlen(entry) == 2) // if the entry is something like 'a1' we must change it to 'a01'
    {
        entry[3]='\0';
        entry[2] = entry[1];
        entry[1] = '0';
    }

    *y = (entry[0]-'a')+1;
    *x = (entry[1]-'0') * 10 + (entry[2]-'0'); // we convert entry[1] and entry[2] from char to int using powers of 10 (10^0 and 10^1).
}
```

`variable` (*naming* is bad I would say- I have never came across a code where variable is named `variable`)  is a local variable, which you want to change someway because of `convertXY`, then either you can pass address o variable or once you done calling the function use `x` and `y`'s changed value to reflect over variable `variable`.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie.: Yep..I edited

Comment: This works, I forgot about this last \0 character. Thanks for your answer. And I'm not aware of ascii values so I didn't know it was that simple to convert !

Comment: @Drakalex.: Take a good book and read it. It will help you. Put a meaningful variable name

Comment: For the variable name I changed it so it shows that's it's just a variable, I thinks it's simplier than keeping the real name which will be out of context. I never name any variable `varialbe` in my code !

Comment: @Drakalex.: You can post of original name here..even if we dont get the context..it looks good.